# util.inspect/JSON.stringify doesn't work on arrays in objects

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am retrieving documents from a mongodb using various comands, find, findones, findoneandupdates, etc. Most of these will return the entire document saved, which i do want. When doing find or findOne mongoose allows for the use of population. I am trying to pass back the entire object that was passed to me or view the whole object but the arrays are coming out wrong. i can still access the values manually but i want the string equivalent of the entire object. I have tried JSON.stringify and util.inspect(). might anyone have a solution to this? I've seen some old posts that address this. I will post my model as well helpful suggestions on changes would be appreciated if the problem is how i am storing the information.

models: first product, second machine:

```
var productSchema = new Schema({
    productName: String,
    produtDesc: String,
    author: String,
    lastUpdate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    minimum: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Machine' },
    recommended: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Machine' }
});

var machineSchema = new Schema({
    cpu: {
        speed: String,
        mfg: [String],
        family: [String],
        cores: Number,
        architecture: String
    },  
    memory: {
        total: Number,
        free: Number
    },
    storage: [ {
        drive: String,
        total: Number, 
        free: Number
    } ],
    os: {
        family: String,
        version: String,
        uptime: Number
    },
    screen: {
        height: Number,
        width: Number
    },
    browser: {
        family: String,
        version: String
    },
    network: [ {
        name: String, 
        speed: Number,
        addresses: [ {
            address: String,
            type: String,
            internal: Boolean
        } ]
    } ],
    software: {
        ".net": [String],
        java: [String],
        acrobat: String
    }
});
```

output code:

```
result.populate('recommended')
    .populate('minimum')
    .exec( function(err, done) {
        console.log(util.inspect(done,
            { showHidden: false, depth: 10 }));
        console.log(done.recommended.network[0]);
        reply(util.inspect(done,
            { showHidden: false, depth: null }));
    });
```

sample output: first util.inspect, second JSON.stringify

```
// util.inspect
{ _id: 553dc1d60062ee501b88535d,
    recommended:
    { _id: 553dc1d60062ee501b88535b,
     __v: 0,
     software: { acrobat: '9.0', java: [Object], '': [Object] },
      network: [ [Object] ],
      browser: { version: '9', family: 'Internet Explorer' },
      screen: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
     os: { version: '6.1', family: 'Windows_NT' },
     storage: [],
     memory: { total: 3072 },
     cpu: { cores: 4, speed: '2800', family: [Object], mfg: [Object] } },
     minimum:
     { _id: 553dc1d60062ee501b885359,
     __v: 0,
     software: { acrobat: '9.0', java: [Object], '': [Object] },
     network: [ [Object] ],
     browser: { version: '9', family: 'Internet Explorer' },
     screen: { width: 1024, height: 768 },
     os: { version: '6.0', family: 'Windows_NT' },
     storage: [],
     memory: { total: 2048 },
     cpu: { cores: 2, speed: '2666', family: [], mfg: [Object] } },
     productName: 'Product Name',
     author: 'chris.lohl',
    __v: 0,
     lastUpdate: Fri Apr 17 2015 07:01:37 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time) 

     }

// JSON.stringify
'{"_id":"553dc1d60062ee501b88535d","recommended":{"_id":"553dc1d60062ee501b88535b","__v":0,"software":{"acrobat":"9.0","java":     ["1.6.0.24"],"":{"net":["2.0","3.5"]}},"network":  [{"name":"ethernet","speed":1000,"_id":"553dc1d60062ee501b88535c","addresses":["[object Object]","[object Object]"]}],"browser": {"version":"9","family":"Internet Explorer"},"screen":  {"width":1920,"height":1080},"os":{"version":"6.1","family":"Windows_NT"},"storage":[],"memory":{"total":3072},"cpu":{"cores":4,"speed":"2800","family":["i3","i5","i7"],"mfg":["intel"]}},"minimum":{"_id":"553dc1d60062ee501b885359","__v":0,"software":{"acrobat":"9.0","java":["1.6.0.2
4"],"":{"net":["2.0","3.5"]}},"network":[{"name":"ethernet","speed":1000,"_id":"
553dc1d60062ee501b88535a","addresses":["[object Object]","[object Object]"]}],"b
rowser":{"version":"9","family":"Internet Explorer"},"screen":{"width":1024,"hei
ght":768},"os":{"version":"6.0","family":"Windows_NT"},"storage":[],"memory":{"t
otal":2048},"cpu":{"cores":2,"speed":"2666","family":[],"mfg":["intel","amd"]}},
"productName":"Product Name","author":"chris.lohl","__v":0,"lastUpdate":"2015-04
-17T14:01:37.000Z"}'
```

Comment: The JSON provided is from console.log(`JSON.stringify(done))`? Sidenote: using `done` as an object name is a bit odd as it might confuse someone later on into thinking it's an async callback function.

Comment: yes done is jsut the object that contains all the info passed by the queries in this case. but the two different outputs are provided by the util.inspect or the stringify call

Comment: You probably want `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)` where 4 is the number of spaces to indent with. This is about as pretty as it gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out sub-docs were the answer to this problem. during the inserting portion to the database i was taking JSON objects and casting them with the constructor for my machine model. new machine(data). This was not being casted until i created schema in my model for a network sub-doc and an address sub-doc for my network's addresses property.

here is the changed model:

```
var addressSchema = new Schema({
    address: String,
    type: String,
    internal: Boolean
}); 
var networkSchema = new Schema({
    name: String, 
    speed: Number,
    addresses: [addressSchema]
}); 
var machineSchema = new Schema({
    cpu: {
        speed: String,
        mfg: [String],
        family: [String],
        cores: Number,
        architecture: String
},  
memory: {
    total: Number,
    free: Number
},
storage: [{
    drive: String,
    total: Number, 
    free: Number
}],
os: {
    family: String,
    version: String,
    uptime: Number
},
screen: {
    height: Number,
    width: Number
},
browser: {
    family: String,
    version: String
},
network: [networkSchema], 
software: {
    ".net": [String],
    java: [String],
    acrobat: String
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(addresses.[0]));

Comment: After pulling an object from the server and trying this all i'm getting is [Object object] its not even letting me see the contents anymore.